# How to create a value-key table of values from struct in C?

Tags: c, dictionary

I have a struct of values:

```
struct Inst
{
    int opc;
    int opc2;
    int opc3;
    int imm;
    int imm2;
    int rs1;
    int rs2;
    int rd;
};
```

For each value, I want there to be a corresponding string that represents that value. So if `opc = 0x3`, then its corresponding string would be `"OP-IMM"`. So value can be an input that I know of. It's just a matter of mapping that value to its corresponding string. Functionally, this would look like so:

```
printf("%s", lookup(opc)) // If the value is 0x37, then it prints LUI, if it's 0x6F, then it prints JAL etc...
```

How would I do that?

Comment: How big the input will be? If the input is limited to non-negative and upto about 1,000,000, you can use simple array in modern PC. (maybe not on embedded environment though) If it will become larger, you will have to think another method.

Comment: i don't get the part for 0x37 why "LUI"? will you provide key/val pairs or the val would determined from key?

Comment: clear up your input/output and also, how you're going to take key/val pair as input into your program/code?

Comment: @reyad sorry I might have explained this poorly. Each potential value in any of the variables should correspond to a unique string that I’ve predetermined. I’m creating a disassembler, and when encoding/decoding the instructions, I separate store each chunk into an int for the chunk. (Opcode chunk gets stored in opc etc) The problem comes when printing the disassembled code. I would just be printing integers. But I want to print what that integer should represent textually. Does that make sense?

Comment: yeah, I got it...so, we may say you've a table where key -> val pairs are already written already and you're just looking up the table: for a key which is corresponding val(which is a string)...am i right? And you want to build that table with look up facility.

Comment: @reyad correct!

Comment: @EthanR You could try to use some form of binary search tree: You have a pair `struct Pair {int op; char* string};`, and then insert it using `Pair.op` as value.

Comment: @EthanR, I've posted an answer, see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does, what you want...I am assuming you don't have much instructions. If you've much more instruction like a Million, you should use `Balanced Binary Search Tree` instead of `array`.(note: I am using linear search to find matching key with an average search complexity of O(n) for each search).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *keys; // this to hold keys
    char **vals; // this to hold valsues or strings
    int size;
    int capacity;
} Table;

Table *getTable(int capacity) {
    Table *table = (Table *)malloc(sizeof(Table));

    table->keys = malloc(sizeof(int) * capacity);
    table->vals = malloc(sizeof(char *) * capacity);
    
    table->size = 0;
    table->capacity = capacity;
    
    return table;
}

int insert(Table *table, int key, char *val) {
    if(table->size >= table->capacity) {
        // couldn't add more key/val pairs
        // capacity overflowed
        return 0;
    }
    // copy val into new dymanic char array string
    int l = strlen(val);
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * (l+1)); // l+1 for null char at the end
    strcpy(buf, val);

    table->keys[table->size] = key;
    table->vals[table->size] = val;

    table->size++;
    return 1; // key/val pair add is successful
}

char *lookup(Table *table, int key) {
    for(int i=0; i<table->size; i++) {
        if(table->keys[i] == key) {
            return table->vals[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void destroyTable(Table *table) {
    for(int i=0; i<table->size; i++) {
        free(table->vals[i]);
    }
    free(table->keys);
    free(table->vals);
    free(table);
}

int main() {
    int capacity = 10;
    Table *table = getTable(capacity);

    int k1 = 12;
    char *v1 = "hello";

    int k2 = 19;
    char *v2 = "world!";

    insert(table, k1, v1);
    insert(table, k2, v2);

    char *val = lookup(table, k1);
    printf("%d: %s\n", k1, val);

    val = lookup(table, k2);
    printf("%d: %s\n", k2, val);

    destroyTable(table);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output for my input was:

```
12: hello
19: world!
```

which ensures that it works properly.

Also, note I've used decimal integer. For use hexadecimal you could as follows:

```
int key = 0x37;
```

And you're done...

[P.S.]: feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You wouldn't happen to be interested in a voice call with perhaps? I have a few questions to ask, but I'm much more comfortable asking them over a call. Zoom or Discord or whatever suits you.

Comment: I am sorry that I'm late...I would prefer if you ask your questions on SO(i.e. here)...cause, it'll help others to understand and solve the problems which are same as your questions...

Comment: Your answer suffices for my question. In particular, though, I tend to have a lot of miscellaneous questions which usually aren't suited for a platform like SO. Either way, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have few numbers (few is relative; actually can be a million easily without problems, depending on the system), and a numbering where all of the possible numbers in a valid range have a meaning, or at least most of them, you can have a simple array.

Let's have the following codes table:

```
0x0: invalid
0x1: "aaa"
0x2: "bbb"
0x3: "ccc"
0x4: invalid
0x5: "ddd"
```

An easy and efficient way to build a lookup table is the following:

```
const char lut[6][MAX_STRINGLEN + 1] = {
        NULL, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", NULL, "ddd"
};
```

And use the string simply by calling the array at the index of the code `lut[opcode]`.

---

In C2x (the next revision of the standard), there is a way to initialize the array with a binary file, which if the array size is very big, can mean a significant improvement in compilation time.